# How to fix a broken Sharp CD-BA150 stereo with the help of a service manual?

Tags: wiring, repair, sound

I have a Sharp CD-BA150 stereo. Since the cd and tape decks are completely busted (doesnt play, rewind, etc.) and I have nothing to lose (I plan to throw it out anyways) I want to try to repair it using the official service manual found here.

http://elektrotanya.com/sharp_cd-ba150_sm.pdf/download.html

I've disassembled the device and am kind of able to match the wiring inside the stereo to the wiring diagrams in the manual. However, how should I start using the manual to solve the problem? I have a good multimeter and proper insulating gloves, and dont mind messing with the device.

Anyone?

Comment: You have to use your creativity to develop hypotheses about what could be wrong, and then use the schematics as a guide in performing tests on the device to confirm or refute the hypotheses. (Scientific method!) For instance, if nothing is working, a hypothesis is that something in the power supply circuitry is shot (possibly just the power entry fuse). So then we check the fuse, and if that is ruled out, we form a few more detailed hypotheses about the power supply and go digging.

Comment: So I just compare the readings on the manual to the results on the multimeter when connected to the same circut? If its different or there is no reading, the resistor/chip/etc is broken, right?

Answer (score 4):

Fault finding is a difficult thing to explain, some people will never get it (including a few professionals I've worked with). There are books and guides out there on it, so a trip round google might throw up some good ones (or others here may have a few they'll share).

I'm no genius at it, but the number 1 thing is to work methodically. Take time, don't jump about, follow things through in a methodical order and keep track of what you're doing.

Number 2 is to stop & think before jumping to a conclusion or changing parts.

It's a common thing that people will just keep changing parts until the thing starts working by luck - this sucks for several reasons: it takes a while, it uses lots of parts, risks damaging things which were working fine (introducing more faults, with different symptoms), and it may be that you fix the symptom but not the cause and the thing will fail again in a while exactly the same.

You do need to know a bit about electronics, how electricity works, and be able to think logically about problems.

In your case, if *everything's dead* then it's most likely the fault is closer to the mains plug than anything, as that would be the place where a single failure (EG blown fuse) would cause *everything* downstream from it to stop working.

If a light bulb in your house stops working, you logically expect it is the bulb which has blown. If ALL the light bulbs stop working at the same time, you go to the fuse box and check the fuse.

Sometimes, dead or burnt components are obvious, but sometimes they are casualties NOT the root cause.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what John said, if there is one basic rule, it's to check the power supplies first.  Without good power, everything else will be flaky and not show you useful symptoms.